# Error making guard statement Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Please consider following:

```
let isHaveSn = model.positions.contains {$0.assortment?.isSerialTrackable == true}
guard isHaveSn else {
return
}
```

isHaveSn product Bool, and so i check that Bool in guard and everything work. But i want to simplify this like that:

```
 guard model.positions.contains {$0.assortment?.isSerialTrackable == true} else {

                return
            }
```

It produce several errors, some of them: expected expression or Consecutive statement should be separated by ;

But i just copy right side of:

```
let isHaveSn = model.positions.contains {$0.assortment?.isSerialTrackable == true}
```

Why my code not compile?

Comment: It's the trailing closure that is tripping you up. Change to enclose the closure in brackets (it's a function parameter in reality). ...`positions.contains(where: {$0`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for that would be:

```
guard model.positions.contains(where: {$0.assortment?.isSerialTrackable == true}) else {
    return
}
```

Actually there was a proposal in swift-evolution to enable trailing closures in guard statements that was rejected. You can read [more about it here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0056-trailing-closures-in-guard.md)

Comment: thanks, still, i think it kind of missunderstanding (because i copy code that provide Bool and paste it in guard and it does not work).